# Script spawner not found on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I was following this tutorial from capistrano:
http://www.capify.org/index.php/From_The_Beginning#Spinners_and_Spawners

But at a certain point, I couldn't go on because I don't have a script/spawner file. So, what can I do instead?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it, it turned into a rails plugin since 2.3

http://www.capify.org/index.php/How_to_use_Capistrano_with_Rails_2.3